# Unable to remove user authentication in NGINX

Tags: authentication, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am using NGINX in Windows 10 and I tested the auth basic in `nginx` by adding `auth_basic` and `auth_basic_user_file` in the default `conf/`, Also I used this to create a password file :

`htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/.htpasswd admin`.

The problem is when I want to disable it.

I have removed `auth_basic` and `auth_basic_user_file`, restarted `nginx`, removed the `htpasswd` file and restart again and the website is still asking for username and password. I also restarted the server and clear the cache in my browser.

Does anyone has an idea what is happening and how I can get rid of this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The browser should react on a simple refresh after Nginx is restarted.
Dissect the problem into pieces.

- Are you configuring right Nginx? Stop it, confirm website is inaccessible.
- Double check Nginx configuration running "nginx -T" (see https://nginx.org/en/docs/switches.html) to make sure configuration is indeed updated.  This will give you a final configuration after all includes (that may add Auth too)